# Google Chrome(mobile) enters an infinite loop opening new tabs when downloading file

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mobile

## Scenario:

I have a mobile phone with android 4.0.3 on it. I have recently installed the Google Chrome browser, and i have a small application(*.apk) hosted on my site.

## Problem:

When i tried to donwload mine application the browser got inside a loop opening new tabs of same address and it cant download my *.apk.

## Some code:

I have this html on my site:

```html
<a id=link href=bee.apk download><span>Install mine application</span></a>
```

The problem occurs when i click on this link.

### Ps: the problem only occurs on google chrome, other browsers can download it properly.

Comment: This bug has been reported before: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411891 Which Chrome version are you using? Are you logged in? Do you have any special settings? Can you reproduce the bug if you use a completely blank Chrome profile (e.g. on your device or in the Android emulator?)

Comment: Chrome v 38.0.2125.114
none special settings, my profile is blank
and yes i can reproduce it yet

Comment: If you have sure that the problem is on Chrome, post it as answer please.

Comment: I am sure that that bug report describes your problem, but I haven't completely figured out yet why it happens (it doesn't happen in the latest Chrome version to me (38)). Moreover, I don't know how to work around the problem yet.

Comment: hmm thats a weird thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove chrome completely and revert back to an older release. The bug may just be in a new release. Some problems are as simple as reverting back a release or two instead of digging to deep just to find a mistake the programmers unknowingly made.

Comment: where i can get a older release?

Comment: Reseting the phone back to factory if it origionally came with it or oldapps.com may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, either wait for developers to solve the issue, if problem is in app, or uninstall current version and install old stable version. 
For archives of old version, search in XDA or any other apk download websites, you will find apk easily.

[FreewareLovers](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/apps), [Xeeapk](http://xeeapk.com/), [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/) 
are few of them i know to download old version apk

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your google chrome settings on your Phone > **Advanced Settings > Content settings > Uncheck Block third-party cookies and site data**  If that works then the problem is with the chrome version you have.